# Laravel Eloquent `take` and `orderBy`

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

When I try to use each of "take" and "orderBy" query, the Model return some records:

`$this->hasMany("App\User")->take(3)`

`$this->hasMany("App\User")->orderBy("id", "desc")`

But when I combine them, it return a null array:

```
$this->hasMany("App\User")->take(3)->orderBy("id", "desc")
```

I run the original sql (from toSql() function)
 and it return 3 records as I expect.
What mistake I get?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the order, it will be:

```
$this->hasMany("App\User")->orderBy("id", "desc")->take(3)
```

This `->take(3)` will execute the SQL query, so you first need to add the `orderBy("id", "desc")` to the hasMany relation.

Comment: I change the order of my chains, but the result just return as I expect when the orderBy is null ("asc" as default).

Comment: If I understand you correctly it's not working correct, you got it in the wrong order or?

Comment: (1) `$this->hasMany("App\User")->orderBy("id")->take(3)`
(2) `$this->hasMany("App\User")->orderBy("id", "desc")->take(3)`

(1) return 3 records, but (2) return empty array