# Eloquent - empty model relation results when "orderBy desc"

Tags: eloquent

I have a query fetching products with some relations, but when adding `"orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')`, The relation with product images becomes an empty array.

I start with:

```
$products = \App\Product::where('id', '>', 0)
->with('designer')      
->whereIn('id', [$someIds]);
```

Then I continue adding some relations with "whereHas" queries (if I would remove those, the problem is still exists)

Lastly, if I do:

```
  return $products
          ->with('gallery.items')
         ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->paginate($args['count']);
```

the `gallery.items` array becomes empty. It works fine if I do `'asc'` instead of `'desc'`. I also tried the `orderByDesc` method , but it's the same thing.

If I change the order, doing orderBy before adding "with" relations, it also returns empty array for the gallery images:

```
  return $products->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
     ->with('gallery.items')
     ->paginate($args['count']);
```

**Edit**:
I can make a simpler query to narrow down the problem:

```
 return $products = \App\Product::take(30)
                  ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
                  ->with('gallery.items') 
                  ->get();
```

^^ This also gives empty gallery items. If I remove `->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')`, the gallery items appear as they should. Also 'asc' works (that's the default sorting).

**update:**
 here is the above ^^ query, logged with `\DB::enableQueryLog()`:

```
      {
                           "query": "select * from `products` 
            order by `updated_at` desc limit 30",
                        "bindings": [],
                          "time": 26.46
                        },
                         {
                            "query": "select * from `galleries` where `galleries`.`id`
           in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 
    ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",

                                "bindings": [
                 3970,3971,3973,3974,3975,3976,3977,3978,3979,3980,3981,3982,3983,3984,
                    3985,3986,3987,3988,3989,3990,3991,3992,3993,3994,3995,3996,3997,3998,
                    3999,4000],
                 "time": 3.64
                },
                {
                                        "query": "select `uploads`.*,
                 `gallery_items`.`gallery_id` as `pivot_gallery_id`, 

                `gallery_items`.`upload_id` as `pivot_upload_id`,

                `gallery_items`.`order` as `pivot_order` 

                from `uploads` 

                inner join `gallery_items` on `uploads`.`id` = `gallery_items`.`upload_id`
            where `gallery_items`.`gallery_id` 
            in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
         ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",

                                "bindings": [
          3970,3971,3973,3974,3975,3976,3977,3978,3979,3980,3981,3982,
3983,3984,3985,3986,3987,3988,3989,3990,3991,3992,3993,3994,3995,
3996,3997,3998,3999,4000],

                      "time": 48.92
```

**Edit 2:**
The gallery.items relation on Gallery model is like this:

```
items(){
      return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Upload', 'gallery_items','gallery_id','upload_id')
                 ->withPivot('order');
}
```

Comment: I would guess that the latest products just don't have any galleries. Did you check the database?

Comment: No they have gallery items. I made an edit with a simpler query where the problem is the same.

Comment: Take() will execute the query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42922008/laravel-eloquent-take-and-orderby

Comment: Matt: it doesn't seem so though, because if I don't add "->with('gallery.items') the gallery items won't be included in the result (otherwise they will be, if not doing orderBy desc).

Comment: Please log the executed queries with `\DB::enableQueryLog(); [...] dd(\DB::getQueryLog());`.

Comment: I added the query.

Comment: Can you provide a https://www.db-fiddle.com with sample data that shows this issue?

Comment: Yes good idea, probably tomorrow evening I can check it out.